# Stored procedure, I have an if else statement where I am executed until the if

Tags: mysql, django

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE valor()
BEGIN
IF (select Garantia from repuestos_repuesto where Garantia = 'N' limit 1) = 'N' then
    Select  re.id ,ve.marca, ve.modelo, ve.año, re.Nombre_repuesto 
    from vehiculos_vehiculo as ve inner join repuestos_repuesto as re on re.Vehiculo_id = ve.id 
    where ve.marca='Chevrolet' and ve.modelo='Aveo Family' and ve.año = '2015' and re.Nombre_repuesto = 'Guardachoque' and  re.Garantia = 'N'  
    Order By re.Precio Limit 1; 
else
    Select  re.id ,ve.marca, ve.modelo, ve.año, re.Nombre_repuesto 
    from vehiculos_vehiculo as ve inner join repuestos_repuesto as re on re.Vehiculo_id = ve.id 
    where ve.marca='Chevrolet' and ve.modelo='Aveo Family' and ve.año = '2015' and re.Nombre_repuesto = 'Guardachoque' and  re.Garantia = 'S'  
    Order By re.Precio Limit 1; 
END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;

call valor()
```

The idea is that in the first if it returns me the vehicles that do not have a guarantee and shows me the lowest price, and in the else those that do have a guarantee, but it does not show me any data when it goes to the else.

[image]

This spare part should print the stored procedure, in the else but it doesn't.

[image]

Comment: Please translate the question  to English or ask it on https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: IF (select Garantia from repuestos_repuesto where Garantia = 'N' limit 1) = 'N'  is always true .. please explain what you are trying to do providing sample data and expected outcome as text..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.